# Enumerable.Range and Memory allocation

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I have the following code:

```
IEnumerable<int> elements = Enumerable.Range(1, Int32.MaxValue);
Console.WriteLine("Size of System.Int32: {0}", sizeof(int));
Console.Write("Iterating over {0} elements... ", elements.Count());
Parallel.ForEach(elements, _ => { });
Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

This prints out:

```
> Size of System.Int32: 4
> Iterating over 2147483647 elements... Done.
```

However, I don't understand why is this not throwing an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Knowing that each `int` value takes up `4` bytes of space, allocating `Int32.MaxValue` amount of `int` should take up **~ 8GB**

Inspecting my application, the process is taking up aprox. ~ 5.200KB.

The elements are being iterated successfully so they must be allocated somewhere, right?

How does LINQ achieve this?

Comment: I would recommend you to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation#Implementation, since lazy evaluation is what LINQ is all about! (and monads ofc!)

Comment: nice try, but c# designers were smarter :P if it was about lazy loading then foreach through the elements would cause memory increase, I doubt it, thouht

Comment: @mikus Who was that a comment to? You know there is a difference between lazy loading and lazy evaluation? (like 50% of the term actually)

Comment: first part was to Mati, and second to you, but indeed, I thought you mentioned lazy loading, didnt read properly, sorry :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`IEnumerable<int>` is not an array. It doesn't store any information itself. The class implementing it is capable of looping over a set of values.

The values here are not stored in an array, instead of that is just iterates and yields the result of every iteration.

Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetRange(int start, int number)
{
    for (int i = start; i < start + number; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

See, no arrays, no storage. It just remembers the current position in the iterator and can execute the appropriate steps to get the next one. This code is generated by the C# compiler on the fly.

Comment: That's a nice, elegant solution there.